# How to collect object using Collectors.toMap if the key is inside a list of child property?

Tags: java, java-stream, java-11

```
class MyObject {
  private List<MyChildObject> children;
}
class MyChildObject {
  private String key;
}
```

My goal is to transfor a list of `MyObject` to a `Map<String, MyObject>` which `String` is `MyChildObject.key`.

My attempt stopped at `myObjectList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(//how to extract key here?, Function.identity()));`

Thanks.

Comment: Looks strange to my, because `MyObject` contains a list children where each child has it's own `key`.

Comment: Which key of the list? The first, the last, an arbitrary one, a random one? What happens if the list is empty?

Comment: I need to map the parent object to each of its children's key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to flatten the Children to make Children's key and `MyObject` pair then collect as Map using `Collectors.toMap`

```
myObjectList.stream()
            .flatMap(e -> e.getChildren()
                           .stream()
                           .map(c -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(c.getKey(), e)))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I think this is what I was looking for.